# Which permissions are required to be set in azure active directory, to access a user's onedrive business account?

Tags: c#, azure, office365, onedrive, office365api

I am trying to provide support for one drive business in my winform application.I am using the one drive REST API for this purpose, as my application in based on 3.5 framework.There are 4 steps for one drive authentication as mentioned on this [link](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm).I am able to successfully complete the first two steps but I get 401 unauthorized error when trying to discover the onedrive business URL for the logged in user.I get following response for discovery URL access token request in step 2:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "scope": "User.Read",
  "expires_on": "1453115649",
  "not_before": "1453111749",
  "resource": "https://api.office.com/discovery/",
  "access_token": <a long string>
  "refresh_token": <another long string>
}
```

I think there might be some problem with the application permissions in azure active directory.So, please let me know the applications and their respective permissions that are required to be set in azure active directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose read/write user files from "Office 365 SharePoint Online"

See attached

[image]

Comment: I have set that privilege, but it gives me unauthorized error when I call the discovery service rest API to get the sharepoint URL for the user.

Comment: I don't think these privilege is enough.As I am not able to get default drive data with this.I think I also require read managed metadata privilege as well.